# What would cause a function not fully executed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity project I have a function like this:

```
void OnReveal(RevealCard r)
{
    print("point A");
    if (guideMgr.guideAnimPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        print("point B");
        guideMgr.guideAnimPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult.SetActive(false);
        GuideMgr.SaveFinishedGuide(GuideMgr.keyGuideFinishedPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult);
    }
    if (!GuideMgr.IsGuideFinished(GuideMgr.keyGuideFinishedSwipeLeftOnOpenPackResult))
    {
        print("point C");
        guideMgr.guideAnimSwipeLeftOnOpenPackResult.SetActive(true);
    }

    print("point D");
    unrevealedCount -= 1;
    if (unrevealedCount <= 0)
    {
        doneButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    print("point E");
}
```

The above codes would run successfully the first time, but the second time it will print out "point A" only. It's very strange to me because I can't figure out why point D or E are not executed. Even when I tried to debug, it runs to Point A, then just jumping out of the function in the next step.

If I change it to the following order or just delete the two if blocks, point E will be executed normally. However since both if blocks are not triggered, I wonder what would cause this problem?

```
    print("point A");
    unrevealedCount -= 1;
    if (unrevealedCount <= 0)
    {
        doneButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    if (guideMgr.guideAnimPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        print("point B");
        guideMgr.guideAnimPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult.SetActive(false);
        GuideMgr.SaveFinishedGuide(GuideMgr.keyGuideFinishedPressOnFirstCardOnOpenPackResult);
    }
    if (!GuideMgr.IsGuideFinished(GuideMgr.keyGuideFinishedSwipeLeftOnOpenPackResult))
    {
        print("point C");
        guideMgr.guideAnimSwipeLeftOnOpenPackResult.SetActive(true);
    }
    print("point E");
```

Deleting if blocks:

```
    print("point A");
    unrevealedCount -= 1;
    if (unrevealedCount <= 0)
    {
        doneButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    print("point E");
```

===========solved============

Thanks to @Noobogami's advice, it's an exception that's not caught be unity logger.
[image]

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, you can attach debugger to Unity and execute the code step by step and see values

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant by mentioning "debug". And the next step after "print("point A");" is getting out of this function.

Comment: Any chance this is being called on a different thread?

Comment: @derHugo They're all on main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems it throws an exception that is not catch by logger. I saw this behavior when there is an error inside a coroutine.

maybe putting a `try/catch` inside your method and try using debugger again will give you a hint about problem.

however it's strange that changing order of `if` blocks will solve the issue and made me thinking that my guess is not correct but I wrote it anyway so maybe it can give you an idea to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly as you said, an execption not caught by unity logger.